# How to remove IT splash screen on PC upon power on?

Tags: windows-7

I currently have an issue which I can't find the solution for weeks now...

Whenever this PC is turned on, it always goes to this attention screen.

[image: w]

Problem is this PC is supposed to startup to desktop automatically and run a program.

Right now, this screen is preventing it.

How to I change the PC settings to bypass or remove this screen entirely?

Comment: is this a computer a ta workplace?

Comment: That appears to be a workplace message. Ask your system administrator

Comment: Off topic as per https://superuser.com/help/on-topic _What topics can I ask about here?... If you have a question about ... and it is not about... issues specific to corporate IT support and networks..._

Comment: this isnt necessarilly a work pc.  it could be a local policy, or he purchased the machine used.  I would reopen and close if it actually is.

Comment: Of that's the case @Keltari OP needs to update their question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 5):

This is a Windows security policy.  If this is a workplace computer, you need to check with your Administrator.  Only he can remove the machine from this policy.

However, if this is a local machine policy, you can do the following:

- click Start then Run
- Enter in `secpol.msc`
- Expand `Local Policies` then `Security Options`
- Double-click `Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on setting in the right pane`
- On the `Local Policy` Setting tab, delete the message